# LINQ query checks if a set contain two records with specific values?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a query that returns true only if a set of data has at least one record with `State == 0` AND another record with `State > 0`

I have this method:

```
  public bool HasHistory(Guid id)
        {
            return GetHistory(id).Any(x => x.State == 0); //&&x.State > 0 ?!
        }
```

I don't know how to accomplish this since most of the LINQ extention methods iterate over each element separately!

Comment: "iterate over each element separately" And where is the problem? You want to check if one element satisfies condition one. Afterwards you check if there´s any object satisfying condition2. This can perfectly done sequentially by iterating the objects one by one.

Comment: If you care about efficiency - just iterate `GetHistory` with foreach, then you can figure it out with just one enumeration. It's not that foreach is somehow obsoleted by LINQ.

Comment: @Evk If `GetHistory()` returns an `IQueryable` (where say the first 1000 records all have state of 0 and then the 1001st has state of 1) then won't `foreach` transfer a lot of data (1001 records) over the wire?

Comment: @mjwills yes it will. For IQueryable another solution will be needed (preferrably one which can return result in one query and fetches no rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public bool HasHistory( Guid id )
    {
        var history = GetHistory( id );
        var check1 = false;
        var check2 = false;
        return history.Any( x =>
        {
            check1 = check1 || x.State == 0;
            check2 = check2 || x.State > 0;
            return check1 && check2;
        } );
    }
```

Comment: Would this work if `GetHistory` returned an `IQueryable` from Entity Framework?

Comment: @mjwills No, for IQueryable needed another solution. I did not think about that ... ((

Answer (score 10):

What's wrong with this one?

```
  public bool HasHistory(Guid id)
  {
      var history = GetHistory(id);
      return history.Any(x => x.State == 0) && history.Any(x => x.State > 0);
  }
```

Actually, if you are working with big data, that's bad, because you are enumerating the collection 2 times instead of one. Otherwise, just use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `&&`- operator to combine the results of different queries:

```
public bool HasHistory(Guid id)
{
    var hist = GetHistory(id);
    return hist.Any(x => x.State == 0) && hist.Any(x => x.State > 0);
}
```

Comment: It won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Aggregate` method:

```
public bool HasHistory(Guid id)
{
    var result = GetHistory(id)
        .Aggregate(new { stateIsZero = true, stateIsPositive = true, hasItems = false },
        (a, x) => new
        {
            stateIsZero = a.stateIsZero && x.State == 0,
            stateIsPositive = a.stateIsPositive && x.State > 0,
            hasItems = true
        });
    return result.stateIsZero && result.stateIsPositive && result.hasItems;
}
```

But this approach will not work with `IQueryable`

Comment: Let's say `GetHistory` returns 1000 items. The first one has status of 0. The second has status of 1. How many of the 1000 items will this code iterate over?

Comment: @mjwills `Aggregate` will iterate through all items. In case when `GetHistory` return in-memory collection it's not a problem. For `IQueryable` @Vladimir Arustamian solution is optimal